# How can I create a helper with Protractor to log me in before my tests run?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In my test, I have

```
var LoginHelper = require('../helpers/functional/login.js')

describe('Passport Navigation', function() {

  beforeAll(function() {
    return LoginHelper()
  })

  it('should properly load the All Skills view', function() {
    browser.get('https://example.com/ng-app/profile')
    element(by.model('myModel')).sendKeys('test stuff')
    element(by.css('btn')).click()

    expect(myModel()).toEqual('more')
  })
})
```

And my helper is:

```
module.exports = function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false
  browser.driver.get('https://example.com/ng-app')


  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys("myusername");
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("mypassword");
  return browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName('input')).click()

}
```

The issue is my site login is NOT an angular site and what happens is (as far as I can tell), it loads the login page, enters the username / password then exits with an error

```
1) Passport Navigation should properly load the All Skills view
  Message:
    Failed: Angular could not be found on the page https://example.com/ng-app/profile.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting fo
r Angular.
                              Please see
                              https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
  Stack:
    Error: Angular could not be found on the page https://example.com/ng-app/profile.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for
 Angular.
```

Comment: Add to protractor.conf:
...
onPrepare: {
  browser.driver.get(url);

  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys(...); ...some wait for login success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

browser.ignoreSynchronization = false, tells Protractor to wait for Angular. If site login is NOT angular, then you should set it to true.

`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`

An example from the Protractor site

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get('/non-angular-login-page.html');

element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Jane');
element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('1234');
element(by.id('clickme')).click();

browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
browser.get('/page-containing-angular.html');
```